# Full width video background CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Не получается растянуть видео по ширине экрана в шапке сайта

```css
video{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

}
```

```html
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="img/Plexus.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
          <div class="w-100 text-white">
            <h1 class="display-3">Video Header</h1>
            <p class="lead mb-0">With HTML5 Video and Bootstrap 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить к `video` `object-fit: cover;` например. В таком случае, будет заполнена вся свободная область контейнера `video`.

```css
video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>

<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>

<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
    <div class="w-100 text-white">
      <h1 class="display-3">Video Header</h1>
      <p class="lead mb-0">With HTML5 Video and Bootstrap 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавил object-fit: cover; все работает спасибо!